# Will CoffeeScript compile in Node?

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I am using Node.js with express to create a web application. My app.js is going to be written in pure JavaScript but I am using external libraries that were written in Coffee-script. What should I call in my app.js so that the coffee-script will compile perfectly and I will be able to use the libraries?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to add the coffee-script package to your project. Once this is done it should be as simple as adding `require('coffee-script')` to your app.js file.

Comment: When you mean add the coffee-script package, do you mean simply add it as a dependency in package.json?

Comment: If you have npm initialized for this project, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

Now you need to include it like this:

```
coffee = require('coffee-script/register');
```

This will register the extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `coffee` command to run your `app.js` to have your external libraries compiled on the fly.

`hello-world.coffee`:

```
module.exports =
  speak: -> console.log 'hello world'
```

`app.js`:

```
mod = require('./hello-world')
mod.speak();
```

From the command line:

> $ coffee app.js

Alternatively, you could compile all of your CoffeeScript to a directory and copy your JS to the same directory with any build tool like grunt, gulp, make, or bash. Then, your JS would be requiring JS and running JS.